# Are countable CW complexes closed under loop spaces?

Tags: algebraic-topology

It’s well know that finite CW complexes are not closed under loop spaces (viewed as homotopy pullbacks). Just consider the circle. Are countable-dimensional CW complexes with countably many cells at each level closed under these homotopy pullbacks? I can’t think of a counter-example but am unsure if it’s true in general.

Comment: I think so and I think the argument should go like this: show that up to homotopy these are precisely the CW complexes with $\pi_i$ at most countable for each $i$ and each basepoint. Then this class of CW complexes is obviously closed under taking loop spaces.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Got it, thanks. This is Theorem 6.1 (pg. 137) of *The Topology of CW Complexes* by Lundell and Weingram.

Comment: It is true and some details are found in my answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3847307/is-it-true-that-all-homotopy-groups-of-a-manifold-are-countable/3847629#3847629) (note that every countable CW complex is homotopy equivalent to a countable locally finite CW complex which is an ANR).